# iOS Having issue with bookmarking SQLite record

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a dictionary application with several data bases , everything works fine except saving columns in bookmark ! , I know , it's not possible change files in NSBundle but I don't know how can I fix it . I would be grateful if you help me out here is the code :

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath {
    NSString *path;

    if ( [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Bv"] intValue] == 2)
    {
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pr-eng" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    } else {

        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"eg-pr" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    }

    if ( [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Bv"] intValue] == 3)
    {
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"german" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    }

    return path;    
}
```

**Here is bookmarking function :**

```
-(void) setBookMark:(NSInteger)oid {

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [[self getDBPath] UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *SetFavSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE DIC SET bookmark=1 WHERE id=\"%d\"", oid];
    //      NSLog(@"%@",SetFavSQL);
    const char *SetFav_stmt = [SetFavSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, SetFav_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
}
```

**Reading database :**

```
-(void) read_Database{

NSMutableArray *DB_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *word_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if(sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath]UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSString *sql =@"SELECT * FROM DIC";

    //        NSLog(@"%@",sql);

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            NSInteger oid = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

            const char* f1 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
            NSString *oName = f1 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f1];

            const char* f2 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
            NSString *oMean = f2 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f2];


            const char* f3 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);
            NSString *oPron = f3 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f3];

            NSInteger bm = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 5);

            readerClass = [[Reader alloc]initWithReadDB:oid Name:oName Mean:oMean Pron:oPron bookMark:bm];

            [DB_Array addObject:readerClass];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);


AppDelegate *appDelegateClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegateClass.wordList removeAllObjects];
appDelegateClass.wordList=[word_Array mutableCopy];


[appDelegateClass.dictionaryArray removeAllObjects];
appDelegateClass.dictionaryArray=[DB_Array mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further improvement in @H2CO3's answer and for more clarification I post my answer :)

Here is what I do to save data to database on iPhone or iPad (iOS). All data is been kept in device locally. So if app is uninstalled all data will lost, if user hasn't take backup of the app and restored if from backup.

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr;
NSString *homeDir;
```

These are the ivar I use in below functions all functions are in my .m file which is contains all my db related functions like update, insert, select, delete.

```
-(void)CopyDbToDocumentsFolder
{
    NSError *err=nil;
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"res_in_mil.sqlite"];
    NSString *copydbpath = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"res_in_mil.sqlite"];
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:copydbpath error:&err];
    if(![fileMgr copyItemAtPath:dbpath toPath:copydbpath error:&err])
    {
        UIAlertView *tellErr = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Unable to copy database." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [tellErr show];

    }
}
-(NSString *) GetDocumentDirectory
{
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    homeDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    return homeDir;
}
```

As the name is self-explains there is no need to explain what these functions are for.

And in appDelegate.m I use the below code to copy my DB to the specified location where I can edit my DB. This code is in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr;
myDB *dbObj = [[myDB alloc]init];
fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dbPath = [[dbObj GetDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"res_in_mil.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if(!success)
    [dbObj CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];
```

I use this for one DB as I have only one DB. But I think you can extend these functions to copy more then one DB.

Even you can make one function to identify that the required DB is in DocumentDirectory or not using the code of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method given above.

And for insert, update, delete, select operation I use the below code to open the DB for any access.

```
fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dbPath = [[self GetDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"res_in_mil.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'",dbPath);
        [self CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi , thanks but please consider I am not using one  data base , I am using at least 5 databases in my project . H2CO3 had answered it ..but my problem  was  :stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sql . is it good for only one

Comment: just add as much ivar like dbPath,dbPath1,dbPath2......etc and copy the database which one is not found in DocumentDirectory at the time of app launch in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method and also at the time of insert, edit, delete, and select method

Comment: You can use multipal if statements to copy that database in documents directory :)

Answer (score 2):

> I know , it's not possible change files in NSBundle

Great, at least you made the effort to google the issue. Then, why not just copy these files to be updated upon the very first launch of the application to some writable path, like NSDocumentsDirectory?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sql"] error:NULL];
```

etc.

Comment: thanks , actually I have to change the data bases from another viewController , so in this line of code :
`stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sql"]` reads only 1 file

Comment: @Momi what is your furhter problem, sorry?

Comment: I mentioned that I am using several databases not just one ! your code works good for only 1 data base

Comment: @Momi euh, but you can write this multiple times for all the database files... Even better, put them in an NSArray and go through them with a for-in loop.

Comment: """what is your furhter problem, sorry""" ~ cut and paste junkies, too lazy to write code I am guessing...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make only one master database and can have multiple tables in it. That can resolve your problem.